# VBScript - "\n" in file path

Tags: vbscript

I want to show `"c:\project\ndev"` by message box but the result print `"\n"` as a new line, hence the actual result is `"c:\project" + new line + "dev"`
Anyone know how to treat this case? I've spent so much time for that but still have no solution.

Comment: I assume you want to escape the backslash as \\

Comment: i tried to use "c:\\project\\ndev" but still become new line at "\n"
so the result is "c:\\project\" + newline + "dev"

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: i'm using win7 Japanese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried two variations on calling the msgbox function on a Windows 8 box.

**Option 1 - Using [sub procedure](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-message-box-using-VBScript/)**

```
x=msgbox("c:\project\ndev",0,"Your drive letter information")
```

*Result*

[image]

Option 2 - Use plain msgbox call.

```
msgbox("c:\project\ndev")
```

*Result:*

[image]

Comment: maybe the reason is my japanese windows??

Comment: That is a possibility.  I am firing up a Win 7 box right now, to verify if that might be the case.

Comment: I just confirmed US version of Win 7, displays the same results as above.

Comment: Could the problem be with something other than the message box?

Comment: I am so sorry! reason is my code. in the past, other wrote this code line <br/> sMessage = Replace(sMessage, "\n", vbCrLf) <br/> so this will always take a newline when meet "\n" @@ <br/>

Comment: Hi @user3667635 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.